# How to revoke access for a particular user?

Tags: shell, permissions, scripting

How can I revoke all access (r,w,x) for a particular user to a file or directory tree (while still giving read permission to others)?

Does setfacl with mask allow this ?

Comment: Is locking the user account not appropriate?

Comment: Thanks but No just want to restrict the user from accessing a particular directory or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes setfacl should do it. Try the below, does it work ?

```
setfacl -m u:user:--- file
```

Where:

- `-m` is to modify the file/directory ACL
- user is the username for which you want to change permission
- `---` will be the no permissions, replacing r,w,x
- file is the name of the file for which you want to change permissions

Comment: @Sutir if this answer works for you please use the tickmark to show it's your accepted answer.